# Java: what kind of ThreadPool should I use here?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I've just started practicing using thread pools. I'm creating a server-client bank app in Java, I went through some of Oracle's documentation and I'm thinking about using a cached thread pool. But I ran a few counting tests and it seemed that the fixed thread pool was faster. The cached thread pool lagged and seem to create too many unnecessary threads. (or maybe I'm doing something wrong here).

My question is, in a real world situation, which would be more efficient? Or is there another type of pool which would be more efficient.

Also, in my counting test I have a few lines:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
          Runnable worker = new serv(10000000L + i);
          executor.execute(worker);
    }
```

In the above lines, are unused threads reused automatically (instead of creating new ones), or is there something else I have to add to make sure this happens?

Comment: If your tasks are CPU bound you may find using a fixed pool which matches the number of CPUs you have is more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an explanation in Executors.newCachedThreadPool() API

Threads that have not been used for sixty seconds are terminated and removed from the cache. Thus, a pool that remains idle for long enough will not consume any resources.

Answer (score 1):

I'm late, you already accepted another answer but here's my take:

I would not recommend using `newCachedThreadPool()` unless you know what you are doing. The reason is that it will create as many Threads necessary to execute tasks submitted to it. This could lead to undesirable circumstances such as running out of descriptors or even crashing JVM because too many threads were created. Although, it does remove idle threads from the pool after 60 seconds but it still causes unbounded growth.

Back yo your question:

> In the above lines, are unused threads reused automatically (instead of creating new ones), or is there something else I have to add to make sure this happens?

It depends. Let's say your each `Runnable worker` takes long time to finish (e.g. 2 minutes). Hence, you will end up creating 500 threads in your loop. Once all the tasks finish, those 500 Threads will linger in memory for 60 seconds and will then be claimed.

If you wish to re-use Threads, use 'Executors.newFixedThreadPool(...)` and specify the number of Threads you wish to use. If you submit more tasks than there are threads, the tasks will wait in Queue until a Thread becomes available.